# Create own type of variable

Tags: c

Is it possible to create a custom type of variable in C/C++? I want something like "super long int", that occupies let's say 40 bytes and allows same operations as in an usual int. (+, -, /, %, <, >, etc..)

Comment: `super long int` ????  You want a `40 bytes` data type ??

Comment: Yes. One that holds an integer.

Comment: What is this "C/C++" you speak of? The languages are no longer as closely related as you might think. Consider how close Old English and German were, and now how close English is to German... The two languages have evolved in different directions.

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++ as the answer will be considerably different in the two.

Comment: Not really, the answer for both languages would be "yes, it is possible."

Comment: If using C++, then roughly: create a class; overload operators and constructors as appropriate; ???; profit.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing built-in for something like that, at least not in C.  You'll need to use a big-number library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).  It doesn't allow for using the normal set of operators, but it can handle numbers of an arbitrarily large size.

EDIT:

If you're targeting C++, GMP does have overloaded operators that will allow you to use the standard set of operators like you would with a regular `int`.  See the [manual](https://gmplib.org/manual/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Some CPUs have support to work with very large numbers. With SSE on the x86/64 architecture you can implement 128 bit values (16 bytes) that can be calculated with normally.
With AVX this limitation extends to 256 bits (32 bytes). The upcoming AVX-512 extension is supposed to have 512 bits (64 bytes), thus enabling "super large" integers.

But there are two caveats to these extensions:

1. The compiler has to support it (GCC for example uses `immintrin.h` for AXV support and `xmmintrin.h` for SSE support). Alternatively you can try to implement the abstractions via inline assembler, but then the Assembler has to understand these (GCC uses AS as far as I know).
2. The machine you are running the compiled code on has to support these instructions. If the CPU does not support AVX or SSE (depending on what you want to do), the application will crash on these instructions, as the CPU does not understand them.

AVX/SSE is used in the implementations of `memset`, `memcpy`, etc, since they also allow you to reduce the memory accesses by a good deal (keep in mind that, while your cache line is going to be loaded into cache once, loading to it still takes up some cycles, and AVX/SSE help you eliminating a good chunk of these costs as well).

Here a working example (compiles with GCC 4.9.3, you have to add -mavx to your compiler options):

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        size_t i;

        /*********************************************************************
        **Hack-ish way to ensure that malloc's alignment does not screw with
        **us. On this box it aligns to 0x10 bytes, but AVX needs 0x20.
        *********************************************************************/
#define AVX_BASE (0x20ULL)

        uint64_t*real_raw = malloc(128);
        uint64_t*raw = (uint64_t*)((uintptr_t)real_raw + (AVX_BASE - ((uintptr_t)real_raw % AVX_BASE)));

        __m256i value = _mm256_setzero_si256();

        for(i = 0;i < 10;i++)
        {
                /*No special function here to do the math.*/
                value += i * i;

                /*************************************************************
                **Extract the value from the register and print the last
                **byte.
                *************************************************************/
                _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)raw,value);
                printf("%lu\n",raw[0]);
        }

        _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)raw,value);
        printf("End: %lu\n",raw[0]);

        free(real_raw);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do SSE and AVX really support integer operands larger than 64 bits? IIRC, they are just to work on multiple operands (int/float) in parallel, so noting gained for OP.

Comment: Initializing and assignment is not supported directly, that's true. But +=, -=, *= and /= work without problem - the compiler automatically inserts machine instructions (vpxor, vmovdqa, vmovq, vmovaps etc) in the binary. See the edit to the post.

Comment: I did not question that, but from their names, I suspect they do not treat the values as a single large integer, but a vector of e.g. 4 (aka quad) "words". Note that `move` and `xor` do not have carry, so there would be no difference between a single very large `int` and multiple smaller "words". But for multiplication, addition, it does.